# Zepto's use of array.filter

Tags: javascript

I am trying to boost my Javascript understanding, so I've been looking through the Zepto library.  I came across this line:

```
uniq = function(array){
    return array.filter(function(item, idx){
        return array.indexOf(item) == idx
    })
}
```

What is the purpose of this function?  From what I can tell, it is creating a new, unique array of elements, right?  But isn't it essentially just cloning the array? If so, wouldn't `array.slice()` be faster?

Finally, wouldn't it increase performance to change `array.indexOf(item)` to `array.indexOf(item,idx)`?  Or better yet, just `return true`?  When does `array.indexOf(item)==idx` *not* equal true?  Is this to prevent duplicate items?  But when would that ever actually happen?

Comment: I feel like the whole use of the `indexOf` is unnecessary. Why wouldn't they just `return true;` every time? I think you're right though, that it makes a clone

Comment: @Ian: that's what I'm wondering.  When will `array.indexOf(item)==idx` not equal `true`?

Comment: Haha as soon as you edited and mentioned "Is this to prevent duplicate items?", I realized what it was doing...and so did a few others who posted :)

Comment: @Ian: yeah... does that mean I should get credit for answering my own question? lol

Comment: I guess technically, but that's not nice :)

Comment: @cegfault or downvotes for not enough research ;-) apparently you updated your post while I was confirming on MDN that indexOf returns the FIRST match.

Comment: @Ian: 'twas a jest, I'm not that mean ;)

Comment: @Christophe Haha it confused me at first too :) And in contrary to - `lastIndexOf` which finds the last

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`it is creating a new, unique array of elements, right?`

It just filter your array elements to return unique elements.

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UBUpM/)

`But isn't it essentially just cloning the array?`

No as I explain above.

`If so, wouldn't array.slice() be faster?`

Slice doesn't remove duplicates.

`Finally, wouldn't it increase performance to change array.indexOf(item) to array.indexOf(item,idx)? Or better yet, just return true?`

If you only return true you won't identify if the element is duplicated or not.

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UBUpM/1/)

`When does array.indexOf(item)==idx not equal true?`

Example:
I have the following array:

`['10', '20', '30', '20', '10']`

**Iterations**:

- 1: `array.IndexOf(10) == 0` ? // yes, so return true
- 2: `array.IndexOf(20) == 1` ? // yes, so return true
- 3: `array.IndexOf(30) == 2` ? // yes, so return true
- 4: `array.IndexOf(20) == 3` ? // no because `array.indexOf(20)` is 1 , so return false
- 5: `array.IndexOf(10) == 4` ? // no because `array.indexOf(10)` is 2 , so return false

So, when the element has already been found it gets false because the indexes are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this code is eliminating duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh I see the "difference" we're questioning. You kinda answered it though, in your edit. I think this method returns a new array that contains **unique** values from the original.

When the `indexOf` method scans the array, it finds the first occurrence of the currently inspected item. If that occurrence is not the same index as the current index being inspected, the `indexOf` result will not equal `idx`. Therefore, it will not return the value because it either wasn't found, or it was found earlier in the array (which means it's a duplicate).

Here's an example:

```
[10, 30, 10, 100]
```

When the `filter` methods goes through the items: `10`, `30`, `10`, then `100`, it will perform the `indexOf` on it.

For `10`, `indexOf` will return `0`. And `idx` is also `0`.

For `30`, `indexOf` will return `1`. And `idx` is also `1`.

For `10`, `indexOf` will return `0`. But `idx` will be `2`.

For `100`, `indexOf` will return `3`. And `idx` is also `3`.

Therefore, `[10, 30, 100]` will be returned, not just a simple clone of the original.

Comment: I gave Ricardo the answer since he was the most thorough, but thanks for all the help!

Comment: Oh definitely, I would agree that's who should get it, and he answered first too...no problem about that

Answer (score 0):

The function (as named) takes unique items in the original array, and returns them in a new array.  So if the original array has distinct items, it will just return a clone.

Remember, `indexOf` returns the *first* index of a given item.  So if the current item appears twice in the array, the filter value will be false.

[For example.](http://jsfiddle.net/2K8nD/)

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = [1, 2, 3, 2];

console.log(uniq(a));  // [1,2,3]
console.log(uniq(b));  // [1,2,3]
```

​

Answer (score 0):

As others have said already this gets rid of duplicates in an array. Just added my answer to show why this works. If you log out the values inside the filter function you'll see the pattern:

```
array.filter(function( item, idx ){
  console.log( item, idx, array.indexOf( item ) );
  ...
  ...

console.log( uniq( ['a','a','b','b','c','c','c','d'] ) );
/*
a 0 0 *
a 1 0
b 2 2 *
b 3 2
c 4 4 *
c 5 4
c 6 4
d 7 7 *
*/
```

Check the last column, that's what determines if the item already exists so the comparison `array.indexOf(item) == idx` checks against the second column, if it's not the same number it is a duplicate. For the item to be unique (`*`) the index and the index position must match.